# How can I set UINavigationbar with gradient color in IOS 11 for new large bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, calayer

I need to make this bar with gradient color. I have already found this question to ordinary navigation bar, but it does not suit for the new large navigation bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For setting background color use this code

```
self.navigationController?.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.blue)
```

For making changes to the text and font use this code

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = 
[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.blue, 
 NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)]
```

Try this